# VB - Listbox DoubleClick event in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listbox, double-click

I want to add a **double click** event to my **Listbox** in **asp.net**

But the only events on a listbox in ASP.net seem to be those:

[image]

Is there a way I could add a DoubleClick event without javascript?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3):

No, I'm afraid not! You can call [`__doPostBack`](http://aspalliance.com/895_Understanding_the_JavaScript___doPostBack_Function) yourself in a js-function from [`ondblclick`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_ondblclick.asp).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 <!--
     function ListBox1_DoubleClick() {
         __doPostBack('<%= ListBox1.ClientID  %>', 'doubleclick');
     }
 -->
 </script>

<asp:ListBox id="ListBox1" 
        ondblclick="ListBox1_DoubleClick()" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Value="1">One</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="2">Two</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="3">Three</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="4">Four</asp:ListItem>
</asp:ListBox>
```

codebehind:

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string parameter = Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"]; // parameter
  // Request["__EVENTTARGET"]; // btnSave
}
```

Comment: +1. Thanks to Javascript you can implement the un-implemented